# Entity Framework Core mismatch in column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do a many-to-many relationship. I have a Customer that can be connected to several CouponCollections but I don't get it to work. I didn't write the code myself and haven't worked with EF that much earlier.

The current error I have, tells me "Invalid column name 'CustomerId'" in CouponCollection when I try to access it. That table has never had a 'CustomerId' column either in the database or in the object, as far as I know.

Is it possible to see how EF is handling the columns and why it thinks that this column should exist? Maybe resetting it and force it to reevaluate all columns.

On a sidenote I don't get migrations to work either. Maybe the problems are connected, but the database just won't update when I change something in the model.

Comment: As I know about many-to-many relationship that you should have the connection table for that relationship.
Could you show your tables in database?

Comment: I thought so too, but then I read somewhere that EF is creating that table if it's needed. I've tried both with and without that table. When I tried with a table I had to create it manually in the database since migrations doesn't work. But the same problem occurs when I have the connection table.

Comment: You need to create an entity that represents the join table in EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many)

> Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are **not yet supported**. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

*Emphasis mine*

Given your issue, you probably need to create the entity to represent the join table as described above.